# How to pass an extended object to a generic array?

Tags: java

In the following (simplified) code, the compiler shouts at the add method (cannot be applied), as explained well in [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/3766649). Is there a clean way to assign my extended class onto the generic array?

```
class a {}
class b extends a {}

ArrayList<? extends a> arr;

void f() {
    arr.add(new b());
}
```

Comment: Not the way you've written it.  You might mean `List<a>`, which would allow you to add a `b`.

Comment: Eventually dropped the Generics and just used the ArrayList arr; Compiler just gives a warning, which may be suppressed with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked").

Comment: that is a pretty terrible idea.  It's better to learn how to deal with generics correctly than to give up entirely on type safety.

Answer (score 0):

`a1` type should be `ArrayList<? extends a> a1;`